# auto restart php-fpm on segfault

Tags: php-fpm, upstart, systemd

I want restart php-fpm after segfaults.
I run php-fpm on ubuntu 14.04 trusty.
It uses upstart for checking services.
I try to set automatic restart with respawn options, but after SIGSEGV php-fpm did not restart. Could you advice - what is the best way to always up php. Thanks.

```
root@xcart5:~# cat /etc/init/php5-fpm.conf | grep resp
respawn
respawn limit unlimited

root@xcart5:~# service php5-fpm restart
root@xcart5:~# ps ax | grep php | wc -l 
2
root@xcart5:~# service php5-fpm restart
root@xcart5:~# ps ax | grep php 
 2786 ?        Ss     0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf)                    
 2799 ?        S+     0:00 grep php
root@xcart5:~# kill -SIGSEGV 2786
root@xcart5:~# ps ax | grep php 
 2813 ?        S+     0:00 grep php
```